# Can IAM user assume a role, if the user is not described in the Trust policy of the role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Can a role be assumed if it does not have a Trust policy?
If a given IAM user has an attached identity based policy saying that he/she can call sts:AssumeRole for a given role (inside the same account), but the user is not described in the Trust policy of this role, will he/she be able to assume the role?

Usually only the resource based policy or the identity based policy should be enough to give rights for the user, but is it different for the roles?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> will he/she be able to assume the role?

Yes, of course she/he will be able to do it, as long the trust policy allows the account to assume the role. For example, a  role has to have the trust policy of:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "<account-number>"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

This way, your **IAM user does not need** to be explicitly listed in the trust policy, but trust policy is required and at least you should specify the account which can assume it. But the drawback is that **any IAM user or role** from the `<account-number>` account that has `sts:AssumeRole` permissions can assume the role.

> it does not have a Trust policy?

Trust policy is required, so you can't have a role without such such a policy.

**Update**

Lets assume you have a role with a  trust policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:user/UserA"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

The role can be assumed **only by userA**. UserB will not be able to assume this policy, regardless of his permissions.

Comment: So no matter that we intend to use the role only inside our current account, we will need to put some trust policy authorizing the current account to use it?

Comment: @Jaxx Yes. trust policy is a required component of IAM role. You can't make a role without a trust policy.

Comment: Let's imagine the following situation:
1. in the trust policy of my Role I describe that user A can assume the role.
2. in the identity based IAM policy for user B I describe that user B can assume my Role.
Will user B be able to assume the role?
(if not, this means that the identitiy based policy for user B for assumeRole is worthless - it does not give him any rights, which are not described in the Trust policy)

Comment: @Jaxx I updated the answer. You are correct, UserB will not be able to assume such policy.

Comment: @Jaxx To make sure it's clear: you can't have a trust policy with no Principal, but you can have one with a very broad Principal. It sounds like what you want is for the role to be assumable by users within the current account (but not, for instance, attached to EC2 instances) so you could set the Principal to be the entire account. Then you define _which_ users have that right using identity-based policies.

Comment: @IMSoP, thank you for the clarification.
My question was more related to the fact that in order to use a role (in the current account), the permission on your user is not enough, you need to have a permission on the role.
Which is different compared to the other resources where only 1 of these (either a resource policy or Identity policy) would be enough. If I have Identity policy for my user that I can access S3 bucket, I do not need also a policy on the Bucket itself.

Comment: @Jaxx I think it's best not to think of a trust policy as an additional _permission_ as such; rather, it's part of the _definition_ of the role, which happens to be written in IAM policy language. A closer equivalent on an S3 bucket might be an [Access Control List](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl_overview.html) which _does_ always exist, always has to allow the request, and generally grants access at the account level.

Answer (score 4):

A Trust Policy specifies the "Principal" which can assume the role it is attached to. That principal can be various different types of entity, such as an AWS service (e.g. to create a role applied to EC2 instances), or the identifier of another AWS account (to grant cross-account access). It cannot be omitted or be a wildcard.

If the principal identifies an AWS account, then it is trusting *the AWS account as a whole*. In a sense, *all* users in that account have been included in the trust policy, but to assume the role they **also** need permission to make the appropriate AssumeRole API call. This *delegates* responsibility to the administrator of the other AWS account to decide which users should be able to assume the role.

This can be used to create a hierarchical arrangement of accounts:

- All users are created in a single AWS account, which has no other resources.
- The actual resources - EC2 instances, S3 buckets, etc - are in separate AWS accounts.
- Each account defines roles granting access to some of these services, with a trust policy listing the central account as the Principal. These roles do not list individual users or groups as trusted, they just define sets of permissions.
- The users in the central account are each granted AssumeRole access to an appropriate subset of the roles in the different accounts. The effect is similar to using Groups or Managed Policies to grant multiple users the same access.

Comment: Could you please let me know if you have any thoughts on the above scenario I mentioned